# Please help me figure out who made this bathtub faucet

Tags: faucet, bathtub

I would like to replace my bathroom shower fixtures and I am having a hard time finding one that is compatible with the current mixing valve and screw placement. Does anyone know this brand?[image]

Comment: Try the tips on[ this site](https://allthumbsdiy.com/plumbing/how-to-identify-a-faucet-brand)

Comment: Please post a pic of the handles/trim.